# How to load XML into HIVE

Tags: xml, hive, apache-nifi

I'm able to parse the XML data into Hive and select the results using Hiveserde jar file , However I'm unable to parse the XML data in Different form below . Can anyone help me to load the XML data into Hive

Notworking format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified"
   xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="points">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="point">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute name="x" type="xs:unsignedShort" use="required" />
            <xs:attribute name="y" type="xs:unsignedShort" use="required" />
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Working format:

```
<AuctionDate>2008-04-28</AuctionDate>
<MaturityDate>2008-07-31</MaturityDate>
```

In the above example , I want the data to be loaded into XML

Maxoccurs and Name column should be loaded into Hive .

Is it possible to do it via Nifi , If so please guide me Nifi configurations.

Comment: This is NOT `XML data`

Comment: This is valid XML data

Comment: People call this as `XML Schema` which defines your `XML Data`

Answer (score 0):

You can load data in a table as 
`load data local inpath '/home/jmdbks/test.xml' into table test_xml;`
see more here: http://atiblog.com/parse-xml-file-using-hive/